# How to get XML from an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

I have an iframe which contains XML string. I want to extract it so as to do processing in javascript or jquery.
Below is the sample iframe

```
<iframe>
    <list>
        <request>
            <name>CourseDaoMarklogicImpl</name>
            <id>spring735cfdc6d848026363b835bfcc69c5026a56d217</id>
            <hits>21</hits>
            <durationsSum>3438</durationsSum>
            <durationsSquareSum>1481952</durationsSquareSum>
            <maximum>688</maximum>
            <cpuTimeSum>45</cpuTimeSum>
            <systemErrors>0</systemErrors>
            <responseSizesSum>-21</responseSizesSum>
            <childHits>0</childHits>
            <childDurationsSum>0</childDurationsSum>
        </request>
    </list>
</iframe>
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Is the XML loaded into the iframe or is it provided as in your example, i.e. as invalid alternative content?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, not an alternative to JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin - it is loaded into iframe using forms.submit()

Comment: fyi if you dont want to use it or need it in iframe you can also do: $('list', XML.somexml).somefunction();

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div>').append(  $(".iframe").contents()    ).remove().text()
```

### edit

I have now seen that it is cross domain.

This wont work

you should use jSonP instead.

Comment: @nikhil.agw: It's cross-domain, you must use a proxy. Otherwise it's a security threat.

Comment: @nikhil.agw it will work if the iframe source is on the same domain.

Comment: `$.getJSON('http://mlan.co.il/Handler.ashx?prm=111&callbackFunction=?', aaa);

          function aaa(data)
        { 
            alert(data.TheMsg);
        };'

Comment: Oh. You meant json. I cant use json. I have to use xml only.

Comment: It doesnt matter you can get also XML from the server.

Answer (score 1):

In case it the same domain:

```
alert($("<div>").append($("list", frames['nameOfMyIframe'].document)).html())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// get the content of iframe and parse it to a jQuery object
var xml = $($("iframe").text());
// find a 'name' element and retrieve the text
xml.find('name').text(); // "CourseDaoMarklogicImpl"
```

### Update:

If it is cross-domain you must retrieve the data in different way. You can use YQL service.

```
var url = ""; // url to your XML file

$.ajax({
  url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
  data: {
    q: "select * from xml where url='" + url + "'",
    format: "json"
  }, 
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); // data is a Object representing XML data
  }
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/oxokup/edit#javascript,live)** is an example.

Comment: @nikhil.agw Yes, it won't work cross-domain. I updated my answer - have a look.